# path to USB drive

Tags: usb, mount

I'm trying to find where is mounted my mp3 player. I can acces it via `Nautilus` but for some reasons I would like to acces it via terminal. And I can't find out where is it mounted. In `nautilus` in the `properties` there is no path to the device, but `mtp://[usb:003,002]/`.

Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    25G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 271,2G  0 part /home
```

Here is the output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="fb722c9f-1d46-4ee3-8424-b97f85f2c459" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="149bb63b-d742-46bd-a7f3-733a546b4dd3" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="31ec965a-f23d-45a6-b694-c5c403fb5817" TYPE="ext4"
```

Here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6449 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 054c:036e Sony Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Look in /media/user in nautilus and you will find it. Or you can mount it manually where you want.

Comment: Referring to your information it can not be mounted.

Comment: I can acces it via `nautilus`, but I need to acces it via terminal. In `media/username` there is only `.` and `..`. When I was trying to find the path in `nautilus` (`properties`) there is no path to the device but `mtp://[usb:003,002]/`

Comment: Is it in /media/mnt ?

Comment: @markkirby in `media` there is only `.`, `..` and user folder, which is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its an mtp device you will not find it in the media folder your using nautilus so you should be able to open it in the terminal by going to this folder

*/run/user/1000/gvfs*

and in there you should find a folder like *mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C002%5D* and that should be your device